# Swift custom string format extension always return 0

Tags: swift, string-formatting

I need my custom string format extension but I have some string format problem.

Here's code.

```
print(String(format: "%.1f", 1.12))
print(String.format("%.1f", 1.12))
extension String {
    static func format(_ format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg...) -> String {
        return String(format: format, arguments)
    }
}
```

output

```
1.1
0.0
```

Why the outputs not the same? Thanks!

Comment: works well for me, on macos 12.3, using xcode 13.3, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. In both cases I get, `1.1`

Comment: I "think" it has to with the way in which the `CVarArg...` is handled (I don't know why). I changed the function to use `return String(format: format, arguments: Array(arguments))` instead and it seemed to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it happens because return type of the format function in extension is `(_ format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg...)` . return must be `String(format: String, arguments:[CVarArg])` .Parameter `arguments`in function is type of `[CVarArg]` and If you use `_ arguments: CVarArg...` instead of `[CVarArg]` in return String format type , the parameter of the `arguments` gonna be `[[CVarArg]]`. It is actually 2d array right now . It may fail because of this.

Also this is not works too

```
 print(String(format: "%.1f", [1.12])) // args is CVarArg...
```

Comment: Yes. I change `return String(format: format, arguments)` to `return String(format: format, arguments: arguments)` and it works fine. Thank you.